# Can't understand the value of a variable after fork()

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h> 


int main(){
    int num = 2;
    
    if (!fork()){
        num++;
        printf ("First: num = %d\n", num);
    }else{
        wait(NULL);
        if (!fork()){
            num++;
            printf ("Second: num = %d\n", num);
        }else{
            wait(NULL);
            num++;
            printf ("Third: num = %d\n", num);
            fflush(stdout);
            exit(0);
        }   
    }       
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Can someone explain why num ends up being 3? I couldn't find a good explanation on fork().
What does (!fork()) even do??

Comment: 'I couldn't find a good explanation on fork(). What does (!fork()) even do??' - I find that there is no correlation between those statements/questions and the facts that may be verified and demonstrated by reference to printed literature and on-line resources as retrieved by a search engine.

Comment: OT:  the function `fork()` has three kinds of returned values  1) >0 means in the parent process.  2) =0 means in the child process.  3) <0  means an error occurred.  The posted code is assuming that a non zero returned value means success, but that is not necessarily true.  Always check all three conditions

Comment: suggest reading: [fork](https://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/c-fork-function-linux-example.aspx).  BTW: why are you using `fork()` if you do not know what it does?

Comment: @user3629249: OP is not using `fork`. This is code they are examining, not code they are writing.

Answer (score 2):

`fork` is a Unix system call that duplicates a process. The program continues running twice, once in the parent process and once in a new child process. In the child process, `fork` returns zero, which is how the child can know it is the child. In the parent, it returns a process identification number for the child. (If an error occurs, it returns −1.)

This code:

```
if (!fork()){
        num++;
        printf ("First: num = %d\n", num);
```

says to create a child, then, in the child, increment `num` and print it. (In the child, `fork` returns zero, so `!fork()` is true.)

At this point, `num` is still 2 in the parent, because it was 2 when the `fork` was executed, and the `num++` in the child incremented the child’s copy of it and did not affect the parent’s `num`.

In the `else` code:

```
wait(NULL);
if (!fork()){
    num++;
    printf ("Second: num = %d\n", num);
```

`wait(NULL)` says to wait for all children to finish execution, then create another child. That child does the same thing as above. Since it had 2 in `num` when it was created, the incremented produces 3, and the child prints 3.

The third piece of code does the same thing. The `fflush` calls are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Fork will create a new process based on the process you have created with your code. So when fork has created a new process it will return 0 for success.

And that is the reason for the output 3.

A detaied explanation how fork works can be found here: [Fork-doc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/)